# Weird Function Return Effect in Python

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
def somefunction(word):

  somelist = word
  
  first_random_index = 2
  second_random_index = 9
  
  somelist[first_random_index], somelist[second_random_index] = somelist[second_random_index], somelist[first_random_index]

  return somelist
  
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y = somefunction(x)

print (x)
print (y)
```

My expected output would be:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
[1, 2, 10, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3]
```

But instead, I am getting:

```
[1, 2, 10, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3]
[1, 2, 10, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3]
```

How is that possible? Why is the original `x` value not printed?

Comment: Do `somelist = list(word)`

Comment: This is because this is pass by reference and pass by value and hence the older value of `x` also gets updated to the new value. Basically `x` and `y` both point to the same memory location and hence if you change one the other also changes